# Why does Itzhak make Nissuin before/instead of Kiddushin?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, avot-patriarch-fathers, parashat-chaye-sara, kiddushin-eirusin

> וַיְבִאֶהָ יִצְחָק הָאֹהֱלָה שָׂרָה אִמּוֹ וַיִּקַּח אֶת־רִבְקָה וַתְּהִי־לוֹ לְאִשָּׁה
>   וַיֶּאֱהָבֶהָ וַיִּנָּחֵם יִצְחָק אַחֲרֵי אִמּוֹ׃
>
> Isaac then brought her into the tent of his mother Sarah, and he took Rebekah as his wife. Isaac loved her, and thus found comfort after his mother’s death. ([Gen 24.67](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.24.67?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0))

As we know from Hilchos Kiddushin - bringing the bride home substitutes Nissuin (closeness, also from ביאה) and "taking as a wife" is only Kiddushin.

So it looks that either Itzhak reversed the Halachic order or was he marrying BY Nissuin (which is Rabbinically prohibited.

I thought about Eliezer's actions that some say constituted Kiddushin, but then the verse is still in reverse order.

How the verse can be explained?

Comment: Could you cite the source to associate bringing the bride home with nissu'in?

Comment: @ba "וַיְבִאֶהָ יִצְחָק הָאֹהֱלָה" means that he brought he into his Reshus and/r had relations as in ביאה.

Comment: That's the statement that I was asking for a source for. (By the way, ביאה is listed as one of the ways of kiddushin, not nissu'in)

Comment: Suggestion: ביהודה מיוחדים את החתן עם הכלה שתהי לבו גס בה. I think that means yichud specifically not for nisuin is not nisuin.

Comment: There is the shita of Rav huna, in kiddushin 4 that chuppa without kiddushin kona. Accredited by Rashi as halacha in Yevamot 57-58

Comment: Nisuin are an addition in kinyanim, e.g. for hafarat nedarim, teruma (miderabanan),

Comment: If Eliezer already effected kiddushin, like you mention, then ויקח of the verse doesn't refer to kiddushin, so there's no problem

Comment: @kouty Right then ויקח is absolutely superfluous.